# Is "sagon" or "sago" the reconstructed proto-germanic term for "story"?

Tags: proto-germanic

I found somewhere that "sagon" is the reconstructed proto-germanic word for "story", which later became "saga" in Norse.

But in other places I find "sago" instead as the reconstructed proto-germanic word.

**Is the correct term "sagon" or "sago"? I am not sure how to verify this.**

Answer (score 2):

The stem is reconstructed as *sagōn-. The nominative singular is reconstructed as *sagǭ (with nasalised long vowel). Of course, this is all hypothetical.

Comment: "The ōn-stems were an innovated formation, created by attaching n-stem endings to older feminines in -ō" [from Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proto-Germanic_grammar#.C5.8Dn-stems), so _*sago / *sagon_ can be different historical stages of the development of the same word.

Comment: @YellowSky. Not without diacritics, of course.

Comment: But basically it depends on whether the question is about a stem or a word.